How to display a GeoTiff (or other geo-coded file) using DevExpress on WPF C#
I added an offline map file that I have already downloaded in the map control. My application is not connected to the internet and the user needs an offline map with (TIFF/BMP/PNG) extension.
Using the tutorial that was available in this link, I wrote the following code and placed it in my project as follows:
<dxm:MapControl x:Name="map" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" MaxZoomLevel="19" CenterPoint="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=MapCenterPoint}" ZoomLevel="17">

      <dxm:MapControl.Layers>
          <dxm:VectorLayer EnableSelection="False">
               <dxm:MapItemStorage>
                   <dxm:MapPolygon EnableHighlighting="False">
                        <dxm:MapPolygon.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Source={x:Static 
                                        properties:Settings.Default}, Path=MapURI}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                        </dxm:MapPolygon.Fill>
                       <dxm:MapPolygon.Points>
                          <dxm:GeoPoint Longitude="51.29086" Latitude="35.44485"/>
                          <dxm:GeoPoint Longitude="51.31040" Latitude="35.44485"/>
                          <dxm:GeoPoint Longitude="51.31040" Latitude="35.43548"/>
                          <dxm:GeoPoint Longitude="51.29086" Latitude="35.43548"/>
                       </dxm:MapPolygon.Points>
                    </dxm:MapPolygon>
                </dxm:MapItemStorage>
          </dxm:VectorLayer>
     </dxm:MapControl.Layers>
</dxm:MapControl>

And I read the path of the map file using binding from the C# side :
private void uMapURI_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     // Create OpenFileDialog 
     Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

     // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
     //dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
     //dlg.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";
     dlg.Filter = "TIFF Files (*.tif)|*.tif|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|BMP Files (*.bmp)|*bmp";

     // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
     Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

     // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
     if (result == true)
     {
         // Open document 
         string filename = dlg.FileName;
         Properties.Settings.Default.MapURI = filename;
         Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
     }
 }

But I want the user to be able to add his (TIFF/BMP/PNG) file. In this method, we have to specify the corner points of the map, and this may be difficult for the user.
Is there an easier solution?
Or can you reach these points using the (TIFF/BMP/PNG) file and replace them?
The implemented code is as follows:

It seems that the DevExpress MapControl has no built-in support for GeoTIFF or world file images. That means you have to read the georeference data yourself from the file(s). For a world file (like a PGW for a PNG image) this is straighforward and explained in the Wikipedia article. For GeoTIFF the data is encoded in the image file's metadata, and you may need the help of a library to extract it.

Is there another solution?
Or using another type of map or using another library

My goal of this project is for the user to give the program an offline map (file type and extension do not matter) and within the program, he can draw lines on the map and place some icons in some places of the map.
What is your suggestion for this project?

That should be possible with any decent WPF map control. It does however depend on what exactly you mean with "offline map". If that is meant to be a collection of geotagged images, the map control should obviously provide support for such images.
